# Proving a floor function

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

I have some non-integer real number (lets call it $b$), then there is some integer (lets call it $i$) that has the the property  $i > b-1$ and $i < b$.

I believe this is a floor function (hopefully my terminology isn't wrong). I was curious on if my thought process on proving it made sense.

Essentially I'd set $b$ to some non-integer number like $9.85$ and then prove it by saying that if $i = 9$ then within the properties given there would have to be an integer between b and $b-1$. In this case it's $9$. I believe this is called a proof by example.

Comment: Your terminology is correct. $i = \text{floor} (b)$

Comment: `this is called a proof by example` There is no such thing. From [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_by_example): "*Proof by example is a* ***logical fallacy*** *whereby one or more examples are claimed as 'proof' for a more general statement.*".

Comment: You only proved that 9.85 has a floor.  What you yet have to prove is that 33.89, sqr 2, pi, -7.8, 3.1 cubed and uncountably many other numbers have a floor.  As that will take forever and ever and a year and a day, your proof will never be in before your deadline.

Comment: Also, just to introduce terminology, you're trying to prove that your function is *well-defined*.